# How to add shadow at the bottom of a div or button?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a shadow of a div or it may be a button. The example can be seen here [here](http://www.surepointexteriors.com/).  On this site in header there is a button "Free Estimate" which have a shadow at its bottom.
This site has used images to show the shadow at the bottom. But I do not want to use images for the shadow. Is it possible to use css to create shadow like that at bottom. Any Help will be appreciated.

have a look at this image I want same kind of `box-shadow`.

[image]

Comment: http://css3generator.com/ Check the BoxShadow generator

Comment: this site will help you. http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Comment: @IndieRok Not like that..I did not find it at css3genertor.com

Comment: @user3777827 don't think negative, everyone wants to help eachother.. its just a matter of time, I understood your point and sometimes without any further info people gave answer what OP I wants.. so be positive. :)

Comment: okhay I understood it by loosing two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this css:

```
box-shadow: inset 2px -7px 11px rgba(80, 92, 51, 0.17);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K6h8k/)

Shadow as you want you can find here with CSS: [**DETAILS**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/)

## [DEMO LIFTED CORNER SHADOW](http://jsfiddle.net/p2yTE/)

CSS:

```
    .drop-shadow {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:40%;
            padding:1em;
            margin:2em 10px 4em;
            background:#fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        }

        .drop-shadow:before,
        .drop-shadow:after {
            content:"";
            position:absolute;
            z-index:-2;
        }

        .drop-shadow p {
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
        } 

/* Lifted corners */

        .lifted {
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            border-radius:4px;
        }

        .lifted:before,
        .lifted:after {
            bottom:15px;
            left:10px;
            width:50%;
            height:20%;
            max-width:300px;
            max-height:100px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
            transform:rotate(-3deg);
        }

        .lifted:after {
            right:10px;
            left:auto;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
            transform:rotate(3deg);
        }
```

Comment: OP doesn't want this effect. you should update your answer now.

Comment: Sweet, I was like "No, use a image for that effect". Css so powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this or u can play with this !

```
 -moz-box-shadow: -1px 4px 12px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 4px 12px #000000;
  box-shadow: -1px 4px 12px #000000;
```

there is many websites available by which you can create css3 effects like box-shadow, text-shadow, radius, noise texture , animation , gradient etc etc .

[Webiste for css3 generator](http://www.css3maker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved, using box-shadow on :before and :after and rotating it.
Please take a look at this [pen](http://codepen.io/sarbbottam/pen/jGzbF)

Markup

```
<div class="btn">
  <input type="button" value="Free Estimate"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

.btn {
  background: #4aad1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.btn:before, .btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px black;
  z-index: -1;
}
.btn:before {
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.btn:after {
  right: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{box-shadow: ;}` to create shadows in css.

Here's an online tool that helps you with that: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

Use box-shadow property in css like this way.

box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -3px #888;